# How to permanently show image dimensions in the tooltip on mouse hover in windows 10?

Tags: image, pixel, display, dimensions

In Explorer, in order to show image dimensions (in pixels) in the tooltip, I did the following :
Display > Details
Right click
Check "Dimensions"

The trouble is when closing and re-opening Windows 10, I have to do the same as above to display again the dimensions.

**Is there a way (by altering the registry ?) to keep the image dimensions permanently displayed in the tooltip** ?

Thank you in advance for any reply.

Patrick